# Automatically register services in Angular

Tags: angular, web, ionic-framework, webpack

In Vue.js I use the technique with `require.context` as documented in in the [Vue Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components)

I was wondering if there's an equivalent for this that works with Ionic Angular so I don't have to add every single service I write into `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Angular docs (https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#using-providedin):

> Beginning with Angular 6.0, the preferred way to create a singleton service is to set providedIn to root on the service's @Injectable() decorator. This tells Angular to provide the service in the application root.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root', // <-- here!
})
export class UserService { ... }
```

So if you set the `provideIn` to `root` in the injectable decorator, you don't need to add that service to the `providers` array of the `AppModule` anymore.

Keep in mind that...

> using the providedIn property of the @Injectable() decorator on the service itself is preferable as of Angular 6.0 as **it makes your services tree-shakable**.